# Within a PL/SQL procedure, wrap a query or refcursor in HTML table

Tags: oracle, plsql

It seems really easy if you are using SQL*Plus to use

```
SQL> set markup html on;
```

and get some lovely results to the SQL*Plus window.  we have an oracle job that runs overnight and sends an email of results to a number of people.  I would like to wrap a sql statement in an HTML table to be in that message.  What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Is the Oracle Job kicked off from the OS? If so you can spool output from SQLPLUS and then email it. If all within the database, you may have add HTML codes to the Pl/SQL code that generates your output. Can you give us an idea of how your current procedure gathers and emails output?

Comment: NO, it is a scheduled recurring oracle job.  Currently we wrap <table><tr><td> tags and concatinate around 32 fields with 4 UNION ALLs.  Making it a major pain to update the output.  What I would like to be able to do is make a view, that would be easier to modify and then wrap that in the HTML markup.

Comment: SET MARKUP is functionality contained in the SQLPLUS binary program, not inside the database. I am not aware of any out-of-the-box way to just blanket apply to a view or table. Closest I know of is HTP package to help with formatting fields as HTTP elements. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15896/pshtp.htm But you will still have some amount of 'ugliness' to get those implemented, it may not save you any complexity. Maybe roll your own pipelined function to take input and format it? THen your view could gather data, and function could handle formatting.

Comment: I was looking a the HTP package and agree it would not save much in complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to generate xml with [`dbms_xmlgen`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB5048), eg:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from dual') as xml from dual;

XML
---
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <DUMMY>X</DUMMY>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Using [`getxmltype`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS69858) instead, it is then possible to apply an `xslt` transform, perhaps like this:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select * from dual').transform(XMLType(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
   <table border="1">
     <tr bgcolor="cyan">
      <xsl:for-each select="/ROWSET/ROW[1]/*">
       <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="/ROWSET/*">
      <tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="./*">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/> </td>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
   </body>
</html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>')).getclobval() as html from dual;

HTML
----
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="cyan">
<th>DUMMY</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>X</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

<sub>nb credit to Tom Kyte for the xslt [from his blog](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/01/9i-10g-version.html). See also [this other post](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/01/i-like-online-communities.html) for a slightly more advanced version.</sub>

Comment: I have to say the "This other post" was the sweetness.  Thanks!

Comment: Let me guess, you preferred the ref cursor? :)

Comment: Oh most definitively!  Though I am most familiar working with it.   I will have to noodle with the solution you gave though, because it could also be handy to skip the declaration of a refcursor.  Any reason to do one over the other?

Comment: Well if you have procedure that handles a `ref cursor` then you can also call it from SQL: "Basically, he has a routine to take in any ref cursor (**any cursor really, I’ll call it from SQL directly**) and convert it into an html table"

Comment: something like `select cursor(select * from mytable) from dual` I think (can't test right now)

Comment: A lot of people don't use cursors much so I thought the plain SQL approach would probably be more useful to others stumbling on the question...

Comment: After working with it a bit I am still happy with the refcursor example.  I appreciate the more general answer you gave though.  Thanks.